# как отключить кнопку на пк юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Увидел что возможно сделать действие на кнопку выключения ПК. Стало интересно, ведь если нажать - выключится ПК. Захотелось сделать скрытное меню в игре. Прошу помощи, ведь не понимаю. unity 2022.3.11f1

Comment: Отключить или скрыть?

Comment: Да, меня интересует возможность отключить действие кнопки выключения ПК на момент того, как я в игре. Просто думаю. что так можно сделать где-то в Project Settings.

Comment: Для этого потребуется как минимум элевация прав пользователя, то есть запуск игры от имени администратора каждый раз, что является небезопасным. А если ваша игра внезапно крашнется и не вернет возможность выключить компьютер пользователю, то он вообще не сможет никогда выключить компьютер. Вы уверены, что это стоит делать?

Comment: Тогда лучше не надо, но мне очень хочется научиться, хочу набраться опыта